# Extracting certain text from a cell in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have an excel file and i need a way of being able to search a certain row of cells and extract that line from the cell and delete the rest of the text around it. not sure what the best way to go about that is. I feel some sort of script in python but I'm not really sure how to go about that. this is what I have so far and I'm stuck now. any help would be appreciated

```
import xlrd
datafile = "test.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        if sheet.cell_value(row, col) ==
```

Comment: Could you read in the excel using Pandas?

Comment: i havent tried that but ill give it a shot

Comment: I would check out https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. I find it easier than Pandas, especially when you have a lot of text or date columns.